# Unrecognized inherited function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Running this C++ Source on Visual C++ 2010:

```
class B{
public:
    virtual void f(int a){}
    virtual void f(){}
};
class A:public B{
public:
    virtual void f(int a){}
};
int main(){
A a;
a.f();
return 0;
}
```

Leads to the following error:

`IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call`

In other words, it seems that `void f()` didn't inherited?

What is the problem?

Comment: And what has the compiler said ? Intellisense is not the compiler.

Comment: @StephaneRolland That's the only error I get

Comment: @StephaneRolland The compiler says: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec0493089623beee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it seems that void f() didn't inherited?

The name f in class A *shadows* name f in B. You can still access foo() from B this way

```
A a;
a.B::f();
```

Other option is to redeclare function foo of B in the scope of A:

```
class A : public B{
public:

    virtual void f(int a) {}
    using B::foo;
};
```

---

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 10.2 Member name lookup

> 1) Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (id-expression)
>   in a class scope (3.3.7). Name lookup can result in an ambiguity, in
>   which case the program is ill-formed. For an id-expression, name
>   lookup begins in the class scope of this; for a qualified-id, name
>   lookup begins in the scope of the nested- name-specifier. Name lookup
>   takes place before access control (3.4, Clause 11).
>
> 2) The following steps define the result of name lookup for a member
>   name f in a class scope C.
>
> 3) The lookup set for f in C, called S(f, C), consists of two
>   component sets: the declaration set, a set of members named f; and the
>   subobject set, a set of subobjects where declarations of these members
>   (possibly including using-declarations) were found. In the declaration
>   set, using-declarations are replaced by the members they designate,
>   and type declarations (including injected-class-names) are replaced by
>   the types they designate. S(f, C) is calculated as follows:
>
> 4) If C contains a declaration of the name f, the declaration set
>   contains every declaration of f declared in C that satisfies the
>   requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs. [
>   Note: Looking up a name in an elaborated-type-specifier (3.4.4) or
>   base-specifier (Clause 10), for instance, ignores all non- type
>   declarations, while looking up a name in a nested-name-specifier
>   (3.4.3) ignores function, variable, and enumerator declarations. As
>   another example, looking up a name in a using-declaration (7.3.3)
>   includes the declaration of a class or enumeration that would
>   ordinarily be hidden by another declaration of that name in the same
>   scope. — end note ] If the resulting declaration set is not empty, the
>   subobject set contains C itself, and calculation is complete.
>
> 5) Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the
>   resulting declaration set is empty), S(f, C) is initially empty. If C
>   has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f in each direct base
>   class subobject Bi , and merge each such lookup set S(f, Bi ) in turn
>   into S(f, C).

Answer (score 5):

Your declaration of `A::f(int a)` hides all signatures `B::f` unless they are exposed to the derived class.  There are 2 good options for exposing the "hidden" methods.

**Option 1**

```
class A:public B{
public:
    using B::f;
    virtual void f(int a){}
};
```

**Option 2**

```
class A:public B{
public:
    virtual void f(int a){}
    virtual void f(){ B::f(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You must use pointers.
2) If you want to get A::f(), you must use A* type variable, but class instance can be of type B* or A*.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class A {
    public:
        virtual void f(int a) {cout << a << " A::f(int)" << endl; }
        virtual void f(){cout << 5 << " A::f()" << endl;}
    };
    class B:public A {
    public:
        virtual void f(int a) {cout << a+1 << " B::f(int)" << endl; }
    };
    int main() {
        A *a;
        a = new B();
        a->f(1);
        a->f();
        delete a;
        a = new A();
        a->f(1);
        a->f();
        delete a;
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
    2 B::f(int)
    5 A::f()
    1 A::f(int)
    5 A::f()
```